# Unable to add ad account in the facebook business manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I created a business manager and connected an application which access level is development.
Create one ad account.
When i try to create another, i receive the following message:

> "You have reached the maximum number of advertising accounts
>   associated with this Business Manager's account. This limit helps to
>   prevent potential violations and fraud. If you need to add more
>   advertising accounts, contact your representative from Facebook or
>   click the gear icon and let us know about this issue. "

When i try to create an ad account through the api, api returns the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
            "message": "(# 275) Ad account can not be determined for this request",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 275
           }
}
```

Can you explain why I can not create a new account, although the level of access for development, you can create 5 advertising account?
Is it possible to create ad accounts without business manager?
Advertising accounts must be linked to the real facebook user?

I will be grateful for explanations of how i can manage ad accounts on facebook

Answer (score 1):

You can contact Facebook support or submit a request for more accounts, they generally give them very easily.

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10204144915803116